# iOS - Child View Controller Having "Strong" Reference To Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I've read a lot about retain cycles. When necessary, a parent `UIViewController` should always have a `strong` reference to its child `UIViewController` while the child should have a `weak` reference to its parent.

Is this ONLY when they're referencing each other? For example, if the parent `UIViewController` DOES NOT have any reference to its child, can the child have a `strong` reference to its parent `UIViewController`? Can I get away with this, or is this bad practice in terms of memory issues coming up in the long run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `UIViewController.h`.

```
/*
  If this view controller is a child of a containing view controller (e.g. a navigation controller or tab bar
  controller,) this is the containing view controller.  Note that as of 5.0 this no longer will return the
  presenting view controller.
*/
weak public var parentViewController: UIViewController? { get }
```

and

```
// An array of children view controllers. This array does not include any presented view controllers.
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
public var childViewControllers: [UIViewController] { get }
```

Here you can see, that there are *already* `strong` and `weak` references between parent and child `ViewControllers`. You **should not** add any more new `strong` references in the direction from child to parent as it can lead to memory leaks.